# Implementing two-dimensional arrays with Maps in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am using a two-dimensional array in some code which I would like to replace with a more suitable data structure in context, namely a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). I would like to use the Map methods, also hope that the performance will improve that way. However, I run into the following problem:

```
const myMap = new Map();
myMap.set([1,2],"some value");
console.log(myMap.get([1,2]));
```

This returns `undefined`. I kind of understand why this is the case, but it is inconvenient. The following works, but it cannot be used in practice. (Imagine that I want to check the map at some coordinate which results from some computation, it just cannot refer to the same coordinate where the Map was set.)

```
const myMap = new Map();
const someCoord = [1,2];
myMap.set(someCoord,"some value");
console.log(myMap.get(someCoord));
```

Are there any workarounds for this? Or are maps not suitable for this kind of implementation of two-dimensional arrays?

Comment: You could stringify the array, and then use that as the key.

Comment: This is an interesting workaround, thank you!

Comment: If you were to stringify the array (`JSON.stringify` or `Array#join`) you could also use plain objects instead of maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different object can never evaluate as true using comparison, you can use strings as key instead of array

```js
const myMap = new Map();
myMap.set([1, 2].toString(), "some value");
console.log(myMap.get([1, 2].toString()));
```